# How to set my OpenWrt routers DHCP to give /32?

Tags: linux, networking, openwrt

How can i set my OpenWrt 10.03 router to not to use 192.168.1.0/24? instead, use a /32 mask, so every client, that gets an ip from the DHCP server just can't sniff the network traffic - it would be a great security feature to safely use e.g.: FTP!

Answer (score 1):

On the wireless side this is done with WPA settings.  On the wired side, I think you would need to set up a VLAN per port.  Then you can setup a /30 or /28 for each port.  /32 addresses are point to point, and I don't think you they will work with DHCP.

Answer (score 0):

How about going to LuCI administration->network->DHCP->additional filed->IPv4 netmask->add?

There you should be able to set up the netmask. I think that the correct setting should be 255.255.255.255. Please do report results!

Comment: i configured it, rebooted the router, but it still gives a C class :D very interesting.. :D https://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=yExS0jQ7

Comment: @user62367 Interesting. I'll check settings on my router and see what can be done.